# How to select from multiple databases in Android Room(How to attach databases)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

As you know we can select from multiple databases using attach command like this:

```
String path = DBHelper.getDatabasePath(context);
String sql = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + path + "/" + dbname.toString()
                + ".db' AS \"" + dbname.toString() + "\";";
db.execSQL(sql);
```

Then by using Cursor, we can do select from them.

By using Android Room, How can I do this? Is there any attachment or similar command to do this?

Answer (score 12):

Can use this code for attach another database

```
@Database(entities = {Book.class, User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class LoanDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract UserDao userDao();

    public abstract BookDao bookDao();

    private static LoanDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static LoanDatabase getInstance(Context context,final String attachDatabaseName) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {{
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                    LoanDatabase.class, "LoanDatabase").addCallback(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    attach(attachDatabaseName,"/data/data/com.test.roomwithdagger/databases/");
                    super.onOpen(db);
                }
            })
                    .build();
        }}
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static void attach(final String databaseName, final String databasePath) {
        String sql = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + databasePath + databaseName
                + "' AS \"" + databaseName + "\";";
        INSTANCE. mDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    }
}

public void attachDatabase(String databaseName,String databasePath){

    String sql = "ATTACH DATABASE '" + databasePath + "/" + databaseName
            + ".db' AS \"" + databaseName + "\";";
    INSTANCE.mDatabase.execSQL(sql);
}
}
```

In Dao interface use `@SkipQueryVerification` for skip query verification like this.

```
@Dao
public interface BookDao {

...

    @SkipQueryVerification
    @Query("SELECT * FROM main.Book b INNER JOIN LoanDatabase1.Loan l on b.Id=l.BookId where b.Id=:bookId")
    Book getBookAndLoan(int bookId);
...

}
```

Use :

```
LoanDatabase db = LoanDatabase.getInstance(this,"LoanDatabase1")

Book book= db.bookDao().getBookAndLoan(1)
```

Comment: what about `@Insert` in Dao, for inserting multiple records, we have to specify main or LoanDatabase1 DB, otherwise table won't be found.

Comment: INSTANCE.mDatabase is deprecated in room.2.2.3


Solution:
SupportSQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = INSTANCE.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);

Comment: If we attach database like this, the LiveData is not getting triggered for me. If I comment attach, then it is triggered. Need help

Comment: LiveData just for this query or the whole LiveData framework goes for a toss ?

Answer (score 2):

While building room database using the [DatabaseBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html) class, you have an option to register a [callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Callback.html) which has methods that'd be called everytime your database is opened:

```
 /**
         * Called when the database has been opened.
         *
         * @param db The database.
         */
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        }
```

One option is to register this callback and `ATTACH` your other database using the `db` parameter. Then in dao, you can have queries which reference the other table.