# How to attach a database in Room?

Tags: android, android-room

I tried to attach database in Android Room like this: [How to select from multiple databases in Android Room(How to attach databases)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015622/how-to-select-from-multiple-databases-in-android-roomhow-to-attach-databases) but i got error when building project: 
**error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: database.table)**
Error concerns

```
@Query("select t.id as tid from mydatabase.mytable t")
public List<MyPojo> getMyTableIds();
```

When I added @SkipQueryVerification, error changed on: **error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type.**

Error dissapears when I remove "mydatabase." from Query.

How to attach database in Android Room and make cross databases query?

Comment: Try use SQLite for that and make async task for your query and as soon as query finish put result in main thread. 
You can do that through the handler way or using runnable method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm downloading a database.db file from Firebase containing some data and merging with my local database

Just keep in mind that ROOM disables Write-Ahead Logging (WAL) if you execute an ATTACH statement. So, if you use ATTACH statement frequently, you can disable WAL during database creation.

In my case, I used the ATTACH statement only once to update the database with latest values. So, I re-enable WAL after the transaction.

```
private fun mergeDatabases(updateDatabase: File) {
    // database is the room database
    val openDatabase = database.openHelper.writableDatabase
    
    openDatabase.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '${updateDatabase.absolutePath}' AS 'merged_database'")

    database.runInTransaction {           
        // PERFORM YOU OPERATIONS
    }
    
    openDatabase.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE 'merged_database'")
    
    // During attach, Write-Ahead Logging is disabled. 
    // So, if you want to enable again, you can do it as follows
    // In my case, I enabled it again because I run attach statement only once
    openDatabase.enableWriteAheadLogging() 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can attach your another database in **onOpen** callback. For details see the answer of another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038938/4544797).