# Room attaching and copying data from database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Android database not being attached using room raw query.

Dao class:

```
@Dao
abstract class SincronizacionInicialDao {

    @RawQuery
    abstract fun executeQuery(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): Int
}
```

Usage in class:

```
val dao = database.sincronizacionInicialDao()

val path = contextWeakReference.get()?.getDatabasePath(dataBaseName).toString()
                    val attachQuery = "ATTACH DATABASE '$path' AS db"
dao.executeQuery(SimpleSQLiteQuery(attachQuery))
```

Database is provided by koin

```
 single {
        val migration_100_101: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            }
        }
        Room.databaseBuilder(
                androidContext(),
                Database::class.java, "database.sqlite"
        ).addMigrations(migration_100_101)
                .build()
    }
```

My database is not being attached using raw query.

Comment: Use this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443436/4776577

Comment: Question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015622/how-to-select-from-multiple-databases-in-android-roomhow-to-attach-databases/50038938#50038938